# Problema click botao python selenium

Tags: python, web-scraping, selenium-webdriver

Estou com problema para clicar em um botão, tentei da seguinte forma

da o erro ElementNotVisibleException: Message: element not interactable

```
pdf = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@class="btn btn-default btn-segunda-via-aberta ng-scope"]')
pdf.click()
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: que erro ocorre?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parece que, quando você tenta clicar no objeto, ele ainda não existe na tela, não está visível ou clicável na hora.

Páginas dinâmicas muitas vezes criam os elementos antes de habilitá-los, ou criam elementos escondidos para depois exibi-los. Quando estamos usando o Selenium é comum que o script execute rápido demais, e chegue em ponto onde tenta clicar em um elemento que ainda não foi exibido, pois o navegador demora um pouco mais para processar a página que foi carregada.

Para mitigar/resolver esse problema é recomendado usar uma das esperas (`Waits`) do `Selenium` (documentadas [aqui](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html)) que seja mais apropriada para o seu caso. Assim o elemento será acessado somente após ter sido criado/disponibilizado. É possível criar suas próprias condições de `Wait`, mas de acordo com a documentação, existe já pronta a condição `visibility_of_element_located` que parece ser adequada ao seu problema.

```
pdf = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@class="btn btn-default btn-segunda-via-aberta ng-scope"]'))
)
pdf.click()
```

Uma outra possível causa: pode ser que o seu `xpath` esteja achando mais de um elemento com esses critérios. Se for esse o caso, o selenium retorna somente o primeiro elemento, que pode não ser o que você quer clicar. Conserte o xpath.

Falhando isso, pode ser um problema mais chato de contornar: O Web Driver tenta simular as ações de um usuário, porém quase sempre há diferenças em relação ao uso real, seja por questões de posicionamento de elementos que são calculados incorretamente ou pela diferença de tempo da digitação/movimentos de mouse. Enquanto um usuário real consegue navegar sem problemas, os eventos gerados pelo WebDriver não conseguem achar os elementos corretamente.

Em casos assim, a solução é substituir chamadas nativas à API do Selenium por "injeção" de comandos JavaScript direto no browser que executam as ações desejadas. Ao invés de `pdf.click()` use:

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", pdf)
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, mas o elemento ja esta na tela quando eu tento clicar nele, na pagina esse é o unico elemento com esse xpath, tentei colocar a sua solução no código e retornou o mesmo erro

Comment: @guilherme adicionei mais uma possível solução

Comment: cara deu certo agora, muito obrigado

Comment: Desculpa abusar, mas eu preciso pegar 2º via de faturas no site, até ai beleza a sua solução funcionou, problema agora é que apareceu a fatura no proximo mes, com outro botao exatamente igual, dando um inspecionar, são dois botões identicos, com mesmo nome com tudo igual, teria como eu diferenciar o click?

Comment: @guilherme tente usar o `find_elements_by_xpath`, com *element**s*** no plural. Ele retorna uma lista de todos os elementos que casam com o xpath. Aí você vai na lista e escolhe: `pdf[0]` ou `pdf[1]` etc

Comment: Show, muito obrigado, salvou minha vida

Comment: @guilherme se a resposta atendeu, marque como resposta aceita, pra fechar a pergunta